# Ocaml function application operator fails

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to learn ocaml but ran into an issue with the function composition operator |>.

```
utop # #require "core";;
utop # open Core;;
utop # Option.value_exn(Some(1));;
- : int = 1
utop # Some(1) |> Option.value_exn;;
Error: This expression has type
         ?here:Base__Source_code_position0.t ->
         ?error:Base.Error.t -> ?message:string -> 'a option -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int option -> 'b
```

I thoght `x |> f` was supposed to be equivalent to `f(x)`. Why does `Option.value_exn(Some(1))` work but not `Some(1) |> Option.value_exn`?

Comment: Looks like the optional arguments `?here`, `?error` and `?message` are getting in the way. You may want to try `Some(1) |> fun x -> Option.value_exn x;;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulties with type inference and optional/labeled arguments is described in [the Ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec44). It mentions that the right way to resolve the issue is to give an explicit type ascription for the troublesome argument, in this case `Option.value_exn`. Indeed

```
Some(1) |> (Option.value_exn : int option -> int);;
```

works. The manual further explains that

> in the specific case where the expected type is a non-labeled function type, and the argument is a function expecting optional parameters, the compiler will attempt to transform the argument to have it match the expected type, by passing None for all optional parameters

but it appears that the polymorphism of `Option.value_exn` interferes with this mechanism. Evidence that it is the polymoprhism that causes the trouble is seen in the failure of

```
let f ?(message = "") x = x in 1 |> f;;
```

for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

No, they aren't equivalent. You can define `|>` operator as:

```
utop # let (|>) a f = f a;;
val ( |> ) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

So, it expects some value of type `'a` and a function `'a -> 'b`.

But, type of `Option.value_exn` is not `'a -> 'b` due to named parameters:

```
utop # Option.value_exn;;
- : ?here:Lexing.position ->
    ?error:Base.Error.t -> ?message:string -> 'a option -> 'a
```

You can specify all named parameters explicitly (makes zero sense actually)

```
utop # Some 1 |> Option.value_exn ~here:Lexing.dummy_pos ~error:(Error.of_string "dummy") ~message:"dummy";;
- : int = 1
```

or just use lambda to wrap it

```
utop # Some 1 |> fun x -> Option.value_exn x;;
- : int = 1
```

Comment: But then, how come `1 |> f` works with `let f ?(b=0) a = a + b` ?

Comment: @rymdhund that’s because b here in an optional parameter, so you don’t have to give it a value. This is different from a named parameter which you must give a value